# Nested tables of 100% width

Tags: html, css

I have a html table which is 100% wide. Inside that are several other tables which are also 100% wide. Below is a simplified version. There are actually quite a few more than 3 in real life.

```
<table width="100%">
<tr><td>
    <table width="100%" border="1">
        content of table 1
    </table>
    <br>
    <table width="100%" border="1">
        content of table 2
    </table>
    <br>
    <table width="100%" border="1">
        content of table 3
    </table>
    <br>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now the problem is one of the tables, let's say table 3, has something like an image in it which forces it to be wider than 100%. That means the page needs a horizontal scroll bar, but also table 1 and table 2 have 100% width, and the extra wide table 3 is wider so there is a gap and everything is misaligned.

One obvious solution is to change tables 1,2 and 3 to all be rows in the parent table and get rid of the br tags. The problem is there is a lot of pages which would need changing in the legacy site I am working on. Is there trick a with CSS that I could use to make the tables all the same width?

Comment: What do you mean, misaligned? All three tables will occupy the full width of the parent (cell). Since the parent is a table too, it will grow, making room for each of the three subtables to be the same width. Example fiddle, where I forced the parent to be small, and one of the children to be wider. As you can see, all three children are wider: http://jsfiddle.net/pwdauj91/

Comment: Can you replicate your issue on jsfiddle.. because when I tried I couldn't... http://jsfiddle.net/sjojn0mq/1/? Which makes sense, because when 3rd table will increase in size, it will force the main table to increase in size which in turn will increase size of table1 and 2!!

Comment: ok will do I need to produce an example which actually replicates the problem it seems

Comment: My problem was actually long text and images overflowing the parent div, not the parent table. I got round it here: http://jsfiddle.net/GrimRob/61fp4u97/ The key thing was word-break: break-all on the table and overflow: hidden on the parent div;